# How does emacs catch scroll events in the terminal?

Tags: terminal-emacs

The exact title. [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34588/does-emacs-use-ncurses-to-render-in-the-terminal) is a somewhat related question. I'd specifically like to know how mouse scroll events are caught when invoked as `emacs -nw`.

Mode 1049 (alternate screen buffer) and [1000](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) (mouse tracking) roughly emulate it but don't get it quite right (for example, click events are caught as well and highlighting with cursor is not possible in the terminal).

I've scoured the source code on GitHub, but there's no details leading me to finding this.

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) that you linked to contains exactly the information you need:

```
Normal tracking mode sends an escape sequence on both button press and
release.  Modifier key (shift, ctrl, meta) information is also sent.  It
is enabled by specifying parameter 1000 to DECSET.  On button press or
release, xterm sends CSI M CbCxCy.
```

Note that last bit: any mouse button press or release event that xterm gets is translated into a sequence of characters to be sent to the application inside. Specifically, it sends `CSI M` followed by three parameters, `Cb`, `Cx`, and `Cy`. I bet you could figure out what they mean just by guessing. `CSI` is defined [much earlier in the document](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-C1-_8-Bit_-Control-Characters) to be the escape character followed by an open square brace. Emacs translates `ESC [` into `M-[`, and when running in a terminal installs a keymap there that does the job of translating the terminal’s escape sequences into commands.

Note that xterm mostly emulates a DEC VT340 terminal, but some things (such as mouse events) are extensions allowing features that the VT340 never had. Most terminal emulators default to copying whatever xterm does, but the specific terminal emulator that you use might not. You should investigate its documentation as well, in case its author decided to do their own thing.

Comment: My mistake, instead of 1007, I had meant to say 1000, but that is not what `emacs` uses, and the difference in behavior can be noticed, as I mentioned. I currently do use the escape sequence `"\x1b[?1000h"`